# How to use ARM software in Raspberry?

Tags: linux, arm

I would like to run [Maestro Control Center](http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J40/3.b) software (for Mini Maestro 24-Channel USB Servo Controller) in Raspberry. But it is not ARM software. It is availabe for Linux and Windows.

I'm total newbie so i have no skills to do it, but i desperately need to do this and surely there is others who would like to do this too.

Comment: You are going to have to download the source code and compile it on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Apparently, the Maestro Control Center is closed-source software (http://forum2.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?p=15475&sid=fb8aa0a3932a6cdd3024275547fa30a1#p15475), so your chances of compiling it for the ARM architecture are rather slim.

Comment: There's also a [thread on the Polulu forum](http://forum.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=6620) that deals with this (though it seems to have died a while ago). You might want to ask your question over there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Without the source code, you can't** (unless you convince the developers to support the ARM architecture).

Long answer: Think of the apps on a phone.  If there wasn't a similar application for your computer, you could not run the phone application on your computer natively. This is also the same reason Raspberry Pi users can't run [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/index_asus.html).

*So how can you get the software you want on the Raspberry Pi?*
To start, you need the source code.  Unfortunately for you, it does not look like it is publicly available.  If you were able to get your hands on the source code, you would have to build it; depending on the size of the source code base, you might need a [build farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_farm) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The general topic of running x86 programs on an ARM system [has come up on *Super User* before](https://superuser.com/q/221549/176100).

You would need to get the source code of the Maestro Control Center and recompile it for the ARM architecture, but since it is closed-source software (as per [this forum post by a Pololu employee](http://forum2.pololu.com/viewtopic.php?p=15475&sid=fb8aa0a3932a6cdd3024275547fa30a1#p15475)), your chances of doing that are very slim, to say the least.

Alternatively, you could try some kind of emulator, but you will be better off searching for an alternative program that is open-source or at least available for the ARM architecture.

Comment: I don't think there is any alternative software and i have asked this in Polulu forum.